# Firestore is incompatible with firebase_auth issue:

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following in pubspec.yaml but for some reason, firebase_auth is incompatible with cloud_firestore. How to resolve this dependency issue?

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: "^0.16.0+1"
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

The error message:

```
Because cloud_firestore >=0.16.0 <0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^3.0.1 and firebase_auth 1.0.1 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.0, cloud_firestore >=0.16.0 <0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 is incompatible with firebase_auth 1.0.1.
And because no versions of firebase_auth match >1.0.1 <2.0.0, cloud_firestore >=0.16.0 <0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 is incompatible with firebase_auth ^1.0.1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `firebase_core` package and update your `cloud_firestore` to the lastest version:

> Before any Firebase services can be used, you must first install the
> firebase_core plugin, which is responsible for connecting your
> application to Firebase. Add the plugin to your pubspec.yaml file

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

```
firebase_core: ^1.0.2
firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm blind. I have used an old version of cloud_firestore.